# Still getting AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile' after trying every thing to solve that

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm still getting this error after running this code with `tf.gfile.GFile` and also `tf.io.gfile.GFile`.Can you help me?

Windows 10

tensorflow GPU version: 2.1.0

Code

```
`import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
 `
```

and also this code:

`

```
 import tensorflow as tf

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.io.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:  
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved this by uninstalling TensorFlow 2.xx, please install the last version of 1x TensorFlow which is [1.15](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions)

If you are using Google colab, use the command to install tensorflow 1.15: `!pip3 install tensorflow==1.15`

Also, you can use `%tensorflow_version 1.x` at the top to make sure only 1x is working for your notebook

Copy both codes from here:
`!pip3 install tensorflow==1.15`
`%tensorflow_version 1.x`